# how can we add tooltip to our logo used as a background image in SSRS charts

Tags: background

I am using SSRS and have used my logo as background image in each chart of the report.I have set source as embedded and have clipped the image and set its position to bottom right.Now I need to add a tooltip and a hyperlink to this logo.Is there a way to do this.

Thanks